# How to show thumbnails in the "new tab" page in Firefox 13+?

Tags: firefox, thumbnails

When opening a new tab in Firefox, I see no thumbnails:

It's exactly what is described in [this ghacks post](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/06/22/firefoxs-new-tab-page-not-showing-websites-or-thumbnails-fix-inside/) (see [the photo](http://cdn.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/no-thumbnails.jpg)), but taking the steps they say does not solve the problem. **I don't erase cache nor history, nor any other external tool does it.**

This happens to me in Fedora 17 and Windows 2003 Server, since I use Firefox 13 (previous versions did not have this feature).

How do I make it work?